# How I can calculate time needed via a function?

Tags: c

I'm a very newbie Programmer!!!!

I tried to write a Code to calculate the time needed to get Driver Licence in the office Based on this Task:

The user enter a Name, an integer of number of available agents, and lastly a string of the other four names waiting for licence separated by spaces.

Program will output an integer of the number of minutes that it will take to get user license.

*** The office says that they will see everyone in alphabetical order and it takes 20 minutes for them to process each new license. All of the agents are available, and they can each see one customer at a time.

Input:
Eric
2
Adam Caroline Rebecca Frank

Output:
40

Here is what I did; I created an array of user name and a 2D array to store another 4 users waiting for licence, I created Sort_Name function to sort the 4 users Alphabetically. Now I want to send name of user, number of available agents and array holding another 4 names to Driver_License function; where the time needed to get Driver Licence should be calculated. Help me please how I can Code Driver_Licence function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Sort_Names (char [][50], int);

int Driver_License (char* Your_name, agent, Name_other)

int main() {
    char Your_Name[50];
    int Agent = 0;
    char Name_Other[4][50];
    printf ("\n Enter Your Name --> ");
    fgets(Your_Name, sizeof(Your_Name), stdin);
    printf ("%s" , Your_Name);
    printf ("\n Number Of Avalible Agents: ");
    scanf ("%d" , &Agent);
    printf ("%d\n" , Agent);
    printf ("\n Other 4 Names: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s" , Name_Other[i]);
        printf ("%s " , Name_Other[i]);
    }
    Sort_Names (Name_Other , 4);
    Driver_License (Your_Name, Agent, Name_Other);
    return 0;
}

void Sort_Names (char Name_other[][50], int N)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[50];
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1 ; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(Name_other[i], Name_other[j]) > 0) 
            {
                strcpy(temp, Name_other[i]);
                strcpy(Name_other[i], Name_other[j]);
                strcpy(Name_other[j], temp);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Re: `scanf("%s" , Name_Other[i]);` --> Do you expect the _other name_ to possibly contain spaces?

Comment: Tip: Don't dictate sizes on arguments like that, use `char**`. The `[50]` stuff in an argument is mostly nonsense, that will decay to a pointer.

Comment: @tadman: A parameter of type `char [][50]` will not be adjusted to make the `[50]` part a pointer. It will be adjusted to be `char (*)[50]` and will not be compatible with `char **`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I mean mostly this kind of spec is frustrating and constraining. Passing `char**` gives more flexibility, so if you architect your structure(s) accordingly it works out better than copy-pasting `50` all over the place.

Comment: My problem is that how I can implement Driver_Licence function.

Comment: Based on this code i have a name (Stored in Your_Name[50]), number of agents (Stored in Agent) and 4 names (Stored in Name_Other[4][50]). I sorted the Name_Others Alphabetically via Sort_Name function. So the last action is to compare the Your_Name[50] with all 4 names in Name_Others[4][50]; after that I can calculate the time needed to get New Driver Licence for Your_Name, because the process occurs Alphabetically and each one needs 20 minutes to complete. Please help me how to can do these steps

Comment: the compiler needs to know the length of each entry in the table.  That is why the `[][50]` is needed

Comment: regarding: `fgets(Your_Name, sizeof(Your_Name), stdin);`  This will store the char array 'Your_Name' including the trailing '\n'`  Usually you do not want to store the `'\n`  Therefore suggest inserting the statement:  `Your_Name[ strspan( Your_Name, "\n" )] = '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find the index `i` where `Your_name` fits in the `Name_other` array. Once we find `i` we need to scale it by `floor(i/agent) + 1` to find the time slot when `Your_name` has been serviced.  Finally, multiple the time slot by `DURATION` to convert time slot to minutes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DURATION 20
#define NAME_OTHER_LEN 4

// Your_name and Name_other uses title case.  Name_other is sorted.
unsigned Driver_License(const char *Your_name, unsigned agent, char **Name_other) {
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < NAME_OTHER_LEN; i++) {
        if(strcmp(Your_name, Name_other[i]) < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return DURATION * (i / agent + 1);
}

int main() {
    printf("%u\n", Driver_License("Erik", 2, (char *[]) { "Adam", "Caroline", "Frank", "Rebecca" }));
    return 0;
}
```

Another way to solve this to create a new array, say, `Names` that consist of `Your_name` and the names from `Name_other`.  Sort that array, then find the index of `Your_name.  If you go this route, it would make sense to not require the argument Name_other to be sorted, as we have to sort it again anyways.

Comment:  Allan Wind 